# Can I use a tantalum capacitor instead of an aluminium capacitor with an AP1509-50SG?

Tags: capacitor, dc-dc-converter, tantalum, aluminium

I am planning to use an [AP1509-50SG](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP1509.pdf) converter in one of my projects.  There is only a very small area to place components. Aluminum capacitors rated 300uF/16VDC or 330uF/25VDC have a large footprint area. I am thinking about using a tantalum capacitor instead of an aluminum one. Will that cause a problem? How should I choose tantalum capacitors?

I have an area of 12x15mm for the IC and the capacitors.

Comment: Please link the data sheet of the IC. Please also explain what a very small area is numerically. Maybe draw a picture?

Comment: How does the ESR compare between the two? How low do you need in your application?

Comment: How do you expect anyone to be able to answer this without knowing any details or what's important for the application?

Comment: Why use such an old and slow regulator for a space-constrained application?

Comment: What's the temperature rating of the application need to be? Tantalum caps are *much* more sensitive to overtemperature than other types, so make sure you're not operating at too high an ambient temperature!

Comment: Also bear in mind that a more modern converter that can run at higher frequencies, as @TimWilliams alludes to, can use much smaller capacitors *and* much smaller inductors. You'll have to balance frequency with switching losses, but there are plenty of converters from TI, LT, and Maxim that can operate at 1 or 2 MHz and might need only 10 μF or so of capacitance due to the higher switching frequency. This 150 kHz converter is very slow by modern standards.

Answer (score 4):

I would not use tantalum capacitors, especially for the input capacitor, they are very intolerant of current surges. If you do, it's recommended you limit the current (for example, by adding a few ohms in series, which may make them less useful) and use a voltage rating at least 3x working voltage to minimize the number of fires.

There is an ESR recommendation (along with a lot more information) you can find in the application note ANP013.

> For the output capacitor, the ESR value is the most important
> parameter.

Eg. for a 3.3V supply with 1% ripple, and 100mA minimum load current, the ESR should be about 150mΩ.

The AP1509 is a part with a very low switching frequency by modern standards (150kHz). I would suggest replacing it with one that operates at a higher frequency to minimize the size of the capacitors and inductor, preferably to allow use of inexpensive, reliable and compact ceramic capacitors in both positions.

Comment: "they are very intolerant of current surges." Did you mean "current"? Or did you mean "voltage"?

Comment: @DavideAndrea Current surges. One major manufacturer says "When using solid tantalum electrolytic capacitors in circuits subject to current surge, such as switching circuits, insert a 3Ω/V or larger resistor in series with the capacitor to limit the current". Naturally they're not terribly useful in many circuits with such a high value series resistor.  And also "**Do not use tantalum electrolytic capacitors in power supply circuits**", if that's not clear enough. And then "if you must.. make sure " voltage rating is at least 3x circuit voltage.

Comment: I can attest to overvoltage conditions causing fire in Tantalum caps, through personal experience :)

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr: forget tantalum, update your regulator to a better one.

Diodes makes the AP63205 with a 1.1MHz switching frequency in a smaller (SOT23-6) package. You can use it with ceramic caps. Linky: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/diodes-incorporated/ap63205wu-7/9858424

The benefits of using a faster switching frequency are less ripple (less capacitance needed) and lower value inductor (less I^R losses). Both serve to improve efficiency and footprint. And yes, efficiency is actually improved despite some increased parasitic loss due to the higher switching rate.

Your 5V regulator can use a couple of ceramic 22uF caps and 4.7uH inductor - resulting in a much, much smaller design than you could achieve with a 150kHz switcher.

As far as tantalum caps, besides their physical and electrical issues, there’s another reason to not use them: tantalum is a conflict mineral.

POSCAPs are a good option if you really need a large value in a small volume, which you don’t if you upgrade your switcher.

Finally, if you’re *really* hurting for space, MPS, TI and others make regulators with integrated inductors.

Answer (score 1):

A tantalum capacitor will work fine. There are only a few, older ICs that cannot handle tantalum due to their low ESR (Effective Series Resistance). This is not one of them.

The lower ESR of a tantalum capacitor allows it to handle a ripple current better than the average electrolytic capacitor.

Comment: My only concern is, can the tantalum handle the ripple current?

Comment: Even better: it has lower internal resistance. "My only concern is" You should edit your question and add that concern.

Comment: FYI, aluminum polymer and tantalum caps are available in a range of ESRs.  Shop around as needed.  As I recall, both are comparable in energy density, and I would prefer to avoid tantalum for the cost, potential failure mode, weight, and use of conflict minerals. In any case, check ripple current in the datasheet, or calculate dissipation from ESR and ripple current (and then use RthJA or estimate it from package size, materials and similar parts).